# How to test operations in a context manager using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest, contextmanager

I have a database handler that utilizes SQLAlchemy ORM to communicate with a database. As part of SQLAlchemy's recommended practices, I interact with the session by using it as a context manager. How can I test what a function called inside the context manager using that context manager has done?

EDIT: *I realized the file structure mattered due to the complexity in introduced. I re-structured the code below to more closely mirror what the end file structure will be like, and what a common production repo in my environment would look like, with code being defined in one file and tests in a completely separate file.*

For example:

Code File (*delete_things_from_table.py*):

```py
from db_handler import delete, SomeTable


def delete_stuff(handler):
    stmt = delete(SomeTable)
    with handler.Session.begin() as session:
        session.execute(stmt)
        session.commit()
```

Test File:

```py
import pytest
import delete_things_from_table as dlt
from db_handler import Handler

def test_delete_stuff():
    handler = db_handler()
    dlt.delete_stuff(handler):

    # Test that session.execute was called
    # Test the value of 'stmt'
    # Test that session.commit was called
```

I am not looking for a solution specific to SQLAlchemy; I am only utilizing this to highlight what I want to test within a context manager, and any strategies for testing context managers are welcome.

Comment: This would be easier if `delete_stuff` didn't rely on a global `handler`. Pass a `Handler` object as an argument, and you can simply pass a suitable stub in place of a real handler.

Comment: @chepner good point; The actual code isn't structured this way anyway so I altered to make it look closer to the truth. We construct the handler in the test file, but the complexity remains because of how context managers work and how you would get the instance of `session` created during the function run.

Comment: Sounds like you need to either patch or spy on your handler, see [pytest-mock](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Yeah the issue isn’t really the context. You need to mock your class so you can monitor the calls.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I am familiar with Mock and using it in this project. However, handler wraps session. session is the contact manager and the object called within the function. I already have handler mocked; a more specific question would be how do I mock "session" to act as a context manager and also be able to test those values. Session does not operate on values within the handler. I left my question more specific to see if there are alternative ways of inspecting the contents of the function.

Comment: @ljmc I have a mock in the handler, but session is wrapped by handler and is used as a context manager. I can shoe-horn a MagicMock into handler.Session.begin(), but how then do I access the values called? I've tried before posting and couldn't come up with a good answer.

Comment: Handler doens't just *wrap* the session; it *produces* it. Depending on what you want to test, if the handler is a `Mock` object, the session will be to (or it can be anything you configure the mock to produce.) Frankly, it would be easier if you start a test database that `delete_stuff` can operate on without modification; then check the database to see if what you think should be delete (and only that) has been deleted.

Comment: @chepner Easier to start a test DB, definitely. But many opinions about unit testing are clear that using test DBs or test APIs or test files are not true unit tests. The philosophy and ethics of that assertion is a separate discussion for another time; suffice it to say I am currently constrained within the school of "test structure musn't use any external services or resources".

Comment: This is not a true unit, as it has external dependencies. Patching any part of the code may be expedient, but it also means you are no longer actually testing the code that will run in production.

Comment: @chepner the example above is not a true unit, agreed. I left out the other sections where I patch out the internals of handler that instantiate the connection for simplicity of understanding the crux of what I was asking. The only external "resource" my actual unit tests rely on is that it can import locally available code from a package identified as "sqlalchemy". The handler code has plenty of unit, integ, and e2e tests to cover problems. This code specifically was meant to test using python scripts instead of SQL for DML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I came up with a solution. I'd love additional/less complex solutions if there are any available, but this works:

```py
import pytest
import delete_things_from_table as dlt
from db_handler import Handler

class MockSession:
    def __init__(self):
        self.execute_params = []
        self.commit_called = False

    def execute(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.execute_params.append(["call", args, kwargs])
        return self

    def commit(self):
        self.commit_called = True
        return self
    
    def begin(self):
        return self

    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass


def test_delete_stuff(monkeypatch):
    handler = db_handler()
    # Parens in 'MockSession' below are Important, pass an instance not the class
    monkeypatch.setattr(handler, Session, MockSession()) 
    dlt.delete_stuff(handler):

    # Test that session.execute was called
    assert len(handler.Session.execute_params)
    # Test the value of 'stmt'
    assert str(handler.Session.execute_params[0][1][0]) == "DELETE FROM some_table"
    # Test that session.commit was called
    assert handler.Session.commit_called
```

Some key things to note:

1. I created a static mock instead of a MagicMock as it's easier to control the methods/data flow with a custom mock class
2. Since the SQLAlchemy session context manager requires a `begin()` to start the context, my mock class needed a begin. Returning `self` in `begin` allows us to test the values later.
3. context managers rely on on the magic methods `__enter__` and `__exit__` with the argument signatures you see above.
4. The mocked class contains mocked methods which alter instance variables allowing us to test later
5. This relies on monkeypatch (there are other ways I'm sure), but what's important to note is that when you pass your mock class you want to patch in an **instance** of the class and not the class itself. The parentheses make a world of difference.

I don't think it's an elegant solution, but it's working. I'll happily take any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: this is how I'd do it :) nice!